# RangeError: Invalid status code: 0, NodeJS ZeroMQ

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, zeromq

I am developing a simple node api/server, that uses websockets, specifically ZeroMQ. However when sending/requesting data, I receive the following error:

**RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)**

```
   var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var server_port = "3000";

/** app settings **/
var zeromq = require("zeromq");
var socket = zeromq.socket("req");/* sends request */
var protocol = "tcp://";
var ip = "192.000.0.000"; //server
var socket_port = "9998";
var url = protocol + ip + ":" + socket_port;


app.use(bodyParser());

/** paths **/
app.post('/request', function (request, response) {
    var command = request.body;

    //connect to port
    socket.connect(url, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("connection error : ", error);
            process.exit(0);
        }
    });

    //response to front end
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(command));

    //recieve request
    socket.on('message', function (message) {

        //output message to console
        console.log("Recieved message @ : " + (new Date().toDateString()) + " : " + message.toString());

        //send response
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');
        response.status(200).send(message);
    });

});


/** start app **/
app.listen(server_port);

console.log("Server started on port: " + server_port);
```

CODE UPDATED: 
Now I am getting:

**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)**

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are sending the status 0. Try using

```
res.status(200).send(<body>);
```

Comment: Hi Skabbi, I have attempted that solution already, however I still get the same error. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Skabbi, I have attempted that solution already, I also tried "setHead", "set", etc, however I still get the same error. The error also points at line19:14... Its still seems the error occurs when it encounters the "response.writeHead"... method.

Comment: I think you are using 'writeHead' incorrectly, the first parameter for writeHead is the status code. 
Looking at the node [HTTP API](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers) it looks like you should be using 'res.setHeader' instead.

Comment: Hi Skabbi, that helped to an extent. It has rid of the former error, however now its generating a new error... please can you help, please see edited post... thanks.

Comment: This is because you are making changes to the response after it has been sent or trying to send the same response twice.

I recommend you look over the [express API](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) a little better. But if you check out the examples for [end()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) it says `Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send() and res.json().` 

So try removing ".end()" at the end.

Comment: Hi Skabbi, I thought that was the problem, and attempted just that, but to no avail. Its still complains about "setHeader"... after supposedly having "sent" data.

Comment: Would be nice to see the updated code without .end(). But I would use console.log everywhere and see where it breaks.

Comment: Each HTTP request can only send one response. And it looks like you are trying to send two responses `socket.send(JSON.stringify(command));` and `response.status(200).send(message);`

Comment: Or more likely,  your ".on('message')" is triggering multiple responses. How often is "Received message ..." logged?

Comment: Yes most likely... the initial send and receive works, however error occurs after the second send/receive message. Cant figure out how to cater for this second request successfully without it generating the error.

Comment: We have really gone outside the scope of the original problem, which I think has been solved. But my recommendation is to stop trying to use a HTTP/socket hybrid.

Comment: Hi Skabbi I experimented quite a bit, restructuring the code, etc... and discovered there is a "response.headersSent" boolean property that helped rid of the error. At this point I have no clue if this has a negative effect on the app, (e.g. performance, best practice), but sure to identify in time. Anyhow, I appreciate the help.